# Request dispatched by checkout_cart_add_product_complete event is missing data

Tags: magento2, cart, http-request

I have an observer which listens to the `checkout_cart_add_product_complete` event in Magento (this works correctly) but when I try to access the `request` data returned by the dispatched event it doesn't seem to work as expected.

The source code which dispatches the event can be found [here](https://github.com/magento/magento2/blob/f2d309a88298886460351c04973a4ff95c7a91c0/app/code/Magento/Checkout/Controller/Cart/Add.php), lines `117-120` dispatch the event and you can see the `request` parameter is present in the dispatched data.

The same source code uses the same request to get the `qty` param, which for example is present in my `request` data.

This is how I am accessing the data dispatched by that event:

```
public function execute(\Magento\Framework\Event\Observer $observer) {
    $event = $observer->getEvent();
    $product = $event->getData('product');
    $request = $event->getData('request');

    $params = $request->getParams();

    $this->myhelpername->log("PARAMS: " . var_export($params, true));
```

Which returns:

```
PARAMS: array (
  'uenc' => 'aHR0cDovL21hZ2VudG8uaW50aWxlcnkuY29tL2NhdGFsb2dzZWFyY2gvcmVzdWx0Lz9xPXRlc3Q,',
  'product' => '2',
  'form_key' => 'F6GFMhoJHPpeoOaa',
) [] []
```

As you can see this is clearly not the same request returned as it doesn't contain the `qty` value. You can see this is access in the [source cod](https://github.com/magento/magento2/blob/f2d309a88298886460351c04973a4ff95c7a91c0/app/code/Magento/Checkout/Controller/Cart/Add.php)e on lines `86-94`.

Any idea why this is?

Note: If I inject my own Request listener and do `$params = $this->request->getParams();` (where `request` is an instance of `\Magento\Framework\App\RequestInterface` then this prints the exact same data as using the above which makes me think I am doing something wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default, when we are in **product listing**, trying to add product to cart, this event is trigger.
However, we cannot get the qty from request. Magento will add product with **quantity  1**.

[image]

If adding a product in **product detail page**, we have a **qty box**. 
If we try to get the quantity from the controller and observer, we can get the values.

```
$params = $this->getRequest()->getParams();

$observer->getEvent()->getRequest()->getParams();
```

[image]